# Javascript: Exception in regular expressions "if not preceded by"

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I check a regular expression to be fulfilled only if there is a number or group of numbers `/\d+/`, but that it is not preceded by a dot?

**Example**:

```
25 = true
.25 = false.
```

Comment: `/(^|[^\d.])(\d+)/`?

Comment: is this what you want `^\d+$`?

Comment: `/^[0-9]+$/` might work?

Comment: Are you looking for something like that? https://regex101.com/r/zFjWnM/11 Your question is not very detailed. It helps if you show multiple lines of example data that should match, and some examples that shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for groups of standalone pure numbers, then consider the following pattern:

```
(^|[^\d.])\d+(?=\s|$)
```

### Demo

This would match groups of digits which are preceded by either the start of the input or a non dot character, and are followed either by the end of the input or whitespace.

Comment: No, the string can start or end as it is, the case is that it contains numbers that are not presed by a point. It is to apply in chemical formulas. The numbers must be converted to subscript, but only if they are not preset by a dot.

Comment: You haven't actually pointed out a flaw in my answer.  Do you see one?

Comment: No, it was really an oversight of mine, the only adaptation I did was to remove the end part. Thank you!
(^|[^\d.])\d+